# how to check where datetime is in between two datetimes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have first pandas dataframe like following

```
 trans_df
 code     price       date           time        product
 12023    71.23       01-01-2018     06:23:00    MS  
 12023    61          01-01-2018     07:56:00    HS
 12023    71.23       01-01-2018     08:34:00    MS
 12023    71.30       01-01-2018     06:03:00    MS  
 12023    61          01-01-2018     11:43:00    HS
 12023    71.23       01-01-2018     10:11:00    MS
 12023    71.23       01-01-2018     04:23:00    MS
 12023    72.23       02-01-2018     10:11:00    MS
 12023    72.23       02-01-2018     04:23:00    MS
```

Now, I have master price dataframe from where I am checking whether the price set in `trans_df` is correct or not basis the transaction date and time is between `effective_date_from` and `effective_date_to` in `master_price` for that particular product

```
master_price
code  price  effective_date_from    effective_date_to  time_from   time_to  product
12023 71.23  01-01-2018             02-01-2018         06:00:00    05:59:00  MS     
12023 61     01-01-2018             02-01-2018         06:00:00    05:59:00  HS 
12023 72.23  02-01-2018             03-01-2018         06:00:00    05:59:00  MS
```

Desired dataframe would be

```
 trans_df

 code     price       date           time        product  flag      actual_price
 12023    71.23       01-01-2018     06:23:00    MS       match     71.23    
 12023    61          01-01-2018     07:56:00    HS       match     61
 12023    71.23       01-01-2018     08:34:00    MS       match     71.23
 12023    71.30       01-01-2018     06:03:00    MS       mismatch  71.23 
 12023    61          01-01-2018     11:43:00    HS       match     61
 12023    71.23       01-01-2018     10:11:00    MS       match     71.23
 12023    71.23       01-01-2018     04:23:00    MS       nan       nan
 12023    72.23       02-01-2018     10:11:00    MS       match     72.23
 12023    72.23       02-01-2018     04:23:00    MS       match     72.23
```

Comment: What is the type of your date? Also, are they MM-DD-YYYY?

Comment: Date is in `DD-MM-YYYY`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert dates with times to datetimes
master_price['effective_date_from'] = (pd.to_datetime(master_price['effective_date_from'], 
                                       format='%d-%m-%Y') + 
                                      pd.to_timedelta(master_price['time_from']))
master_price['effective_date_to'] = (pd.to_datetime(master_price['effective_date_to'], 
                                     format='%d-%m-%Y') + 
                                     pd.to_timedelta(master_price['time_to']))
trans_df['date'] = (pd.to_datetime(trans_df['date'], format='%d-%m-%Y') +
                    pd.to_timedelta(trans_df['time']))

#join together and filter between 
df = trans_df.merge(master_price, on=['code','product'], how='left')
df = df[df.date.between(df.effective_date_from, df.effective_date_to)]

#add only filterd rows to original
df = trans_df.merge(df, on=['code','product','date','time'], how='left')
cols = ['effective_date_from', 'effective_date_to', 'time_to','time_from','price_x']
df = df.drop(cols, axis=1)
#first test missing values then match.mismatch
df['flag'] = np.select([df['price_y'].isnull(), 
                        df['price_y'] == df['price']], 
                       [np.nan, 'match'], default='mismatch')
df = df.rename(columns={'price_y':'actual_price'})
print (df)
    code  price                date      time product  actual_price      flag
0  12023  71.23 2018-01-01 06:23:00  06:23:00      MS         71.23     match
1  12023  61.00 2018-01-01 07:56:00  07:56:00      HS         61.00     match
2  12023  71.23 2018-01-01 08:34:00  08:34:00      MS         71.23     match
3  12023  71.30 2018-01-01 06:03:00  06:03:00      MS         71.23  mismatch
4  12023  61.00 2018-01-01 11:43:00  11:43:00      HS         61.00     match
5  12023  71.23 2018-01-01 10:11:00  10:11:00      MS         71.23     match
6  12023  71.23 2018-01-01 04:23:00  04:23:00      MS           NaN       nan
7  12023  72.23 2018-01-02 10:11:00  10:11:00      MS         72.23     match
8  12023  72.23 2018-01-02 04:23:00  04:23:00      MS         71.23  mismatch
```

Comment: I have multiple dates in trans_df and master_price, so at the time of joining these two dataframes we will also have to use date?

Comment: @Neil - hmmm, need only one datetime column, one possible solution for do it is use `melt`. Unfortunately it create more rows, so solution should be memory consumed. Another solution should be create function, loop each row and match. This solution is slow :(

Comment: updated my question. If we want to use if loop, then will it be too slow?

Comment: @Neil - it depends what is size of both DataFrames.

Comment: 2-3 lacs records in transaction df and ~2k entries in master price df

Comment: @Neil - it is a lot of... Now thinking if not possible use this solution with modification like `df = df[df.date.between(df.effective_date_from, df.effective_date_to) | df.date.between(df.effective_date_from1, df.effective_date_to2)]`

Comment: `df = trans_df.merge(master_price, on=['code','product'], how='left')` this remains same or do we have to add date as well?

Comment: @Neil - I think yes, because need to join columns by these 2 columns only

Comment: If we want to use if loop which will loop over all the transaction and make the comparison how can we do it?

Comment: @Neil - hmmm, can you change data for this? Or create new question? Because not sure if understand each other for 100%. Thanks.

Comment: sure I will do that.

Comment: @Neil - I read conversation under new question now, better is add link under some my answer, because I am not notify and some users should be angry...

Comment: @Neil - working with your new question and is `master_price` correct? Because datetime ranges are overlaping, e.g. for first and second row fr same code and same product.

Comment: there can be two price changes in the same day.

Comment: So it is really problem. You need change datetimes from and to to unique ranges and some fast non loop solution is not easy (I guess loop solution should be not easy too :( )

Comment: I see. anything else we can do about it?

Comment: @Neil - Main problem is change datetimes for non overlaping and then use this answer.

Comment: considering unique price master data what would be the solution ?